# How to allow feature/polygon to be edited with Leaflet.draw?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

i have a simple .json file and i draw it to map using leaflet,
now it should be editable using leaflet.draw toolbar,and when ever we edit (marker,polygon..) its json file should be update.
I don't have clue to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet.Draw puts its editable layers in a featureGroup. When you defined L.Draw options, you may have written something like that :

```
edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers,
    remove: false
}
```

Every layer drawn by hand is added to `editableLayers` feature group. If you add each layers created by your json import in the feature group. They will be editable when you press the "edit" button. Abstract example :

```
var jsonlayer = new L.geoJson(jsoncontent, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
        editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
    }
});
```